# Problem with onchange, it isn't recognizing scss files changes

Tags: npm, scripting

I installed the onchange plugin into my project but I cant get the script to run when i execute "watch:scss" on npm, it just doesn't detect any changes on my files, maybe it's a syntax error but I checked it a lot of times, hope someone can help :)

```
    {
  "name": "guia-hoteles",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Primer proyecto de Node.js",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "lite-server",
    "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
    "watch:scss": "onchange 'css/*.scss' -- npm run scss ",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run dev\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://juani_olguin@bitbucket.org/juani_olguin/guia-hoteles.git"
  },
  "author": "Juan Ignacio Olguin",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/juani_olguin/guia-hoteles#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "onchange": "^7.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.5.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "open-iconic": "^1.1.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  }
}
```

[this is what git looks like when I run the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfDDv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows, basically you just need to change single quotes with double quotes and escape the double quotes, like this:

```
"watch:scss": "onchange \\"css/*.scss\\" -- npm run scss ",
```